# If cable (coaxial cable TV / cable internet access) is shared, what is preventing DOS attacks?

Tags: cable, topology, docsis

If I simply blasted a continuous signal, wouldn't I make the entire network unusable?How do users (modems) even know when they can send their data (is something like CSMA/CD used?)?I assume there's a multiplexer for each building / neighbourhood that takes care of medium access control which would also prevent any denial of service.

Comment: Unfortunately, there is a lot of foundation you are missing, and a complete answer is really too large for this site.

Comment: Entire network? No. Your local segment ("node")? Sure. What keeps people from doing this? The desire to not go to jail. It's a felony in the US.

Comment: It's incredible how everything is too broad on stack exchange.What am I supposed to ask then?You might have at least recommended something to find an answer myself.I guess closing questions is easier.